# Getting 404 error while using get_headers for my other site

Tags: php, apache, curl, http-headers, http-status-code-404

I am facing a problem and I can't figure it out. 
I want to get data from my other site using file_get_contents or curl and I am verifying first that file exists on the other server but I am getting 404 error that file doesn't exist even file exist on the server.

```
$fileBlue = 'http://theblueish.com/file.txt';  // File on my other server
echo 'Url is: '.$fileBlue.'<br>';
$file_headers = get_headers($fileBlue); 
print_r($file_headers);
```

OutPut

```
Url is: http://theblueish.com/file.txt
Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found [1] => Date: Sun, 29 May 2016 06:13:38 GMT [2] => Server: Apache [3] => Content-Length: 325 [4] => Connection: close [5] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 )
```

And when I try Online HTTP header check site it returns 200 OK 
http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php

Please help me out what could be the issue why server is giving me 404 error . Thanks

Comment: It works for me. I get 200 ok response. May be something with permissions/php.ini.

Can you post your phpinfo(); output?

Comment: Here is the phpinfo http://theblueish.com/phpinfo.php

Answer (score 0):

Please see in order to do this, you must set `allow_url_fopen = On;` in php.ini

Comment: It is set ON to both sites from which I am running the script and on the other site too

Comment: @ADoe, set this on server where you run script.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in redirects(304). I recommend for you use `curl`, like this:

```
$fileBlue = 'http://theblueish.com/file.txt';  // File on my other server
$ch = curl_init($fileBlue);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
echo 'Url is: '.$fileBlue.'<br>';
$file_headers = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($file_headers);
```

Comment: Still got 404 error
`Url is: http://theblueish.com/file.txt
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found Date: Sun, 29 May 2016 06:41:08 GMT Server: Apache Content-Length: 325 Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Not Found

The requested URL /file.txt was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
1`

Comment: If I run same script on other server I am  getting 200 OK but 404 on the server from which I am working

Comment: Hm, like problem is in DNS. Please show for begin your `hosts` file. Or show `ping theblueish.com` result.

Comment: I solved the issue. It was firewall on cpanel which was not allowing to connect to that site now it is working